# Entries in history

Tags: password, mysql, history

I usually include the password when I log in to *MySQL*. How do I exclude `mysql -u root -pPassword` being picked up and stored by *history*?

Comment: Just use `mysql -u root -p` and then type the password when asked for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a space before your command.

This will work because, by default, the variable `$HISTCONTROL` contains `ignoreboth` which means `ignorespace` and `ignoredups`; `ignorespace` is what makes bash not save the command in history when there is a leading space.

From [`man bash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

```
  HISTCONTROL
              A  colon-separated list of values controlling how commands are saved on the history list.  If the list of
              values includes ignorespace, lines which begin with a space character are not saved in the history  list.
              A  value  of  ignoredups  causes  lines  matching the previous history entry to not be saved.  A value of
              ignoreboth is shorthand for ignorespace and ignoredups.  A value of erasedups causes all  previous  lines
              matching  the  current line to be removed from the history list before that line is saved.  Any value not
              in the above list is ignored.  If HISTCONTROL is unset, or does not include a valid value, all lines read
              by  the  shell  parser are saved on the history list, subject to the value of HISTIGNORE.  The second and
              subsequent lines of a multi-line compound command are not tested, and are added to the history regardless
              of the value of HISTCONTROL.
```

---

If you want to exclude a certain command from Bash's history system wide, add the following to your `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
HISTIGNORE='mysql*'
```

This will exclude any command that starts with `mysql`.

Execute `source /etc/bash.bashrc` to apply the changes.

> Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32460/excluding-some-of-the-commands-from-being-getting-stored-in-bash-history

Comment: I know. It's a db server which is accessed by many people, so I need a generic entry to include etc. in the `bashrc` file.

Comment: @nicoX check the updated answer.

Comment: `source /etc/bash.bashrc` to load the changes on the fly, after including the snippet to `bash.bashrc`.